# Apple Watch Main menu screen in the Emulator

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

When i Launch an watch app, it shows the watch app screen that we designed. How can we see the Home screen of an apple watch in the Emulator.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible, at least not yet.

In Xcode you have to choose which target scheme (app or glance) you want to run in the simulator.

I think Apple does not want to show what the Apple Watch might look like before it is released.

Comment: I don't think they will change the home screen, Maybe if we have the Digital crown in the Emulator, we can see the menu..

Comment: This is the first thing which I tried, even command + H has no effect. Its possible that Apple is has not yet completely developed the default apps which is why we are not able to see it.

Answer (score 3):

Now possible in Xcode 7! Going to the Home option in the menu under Hardware (Cmd+Shift+H) takes you to the apps view home screen.

Answer (score 1):

Select Watch Simulator->Hardware Menu->Home at any version of  XCode after 7.